# How to use component from altair admin theme in another page?

Tags: angularjs, templates, themes

I am trying to use one of the components from altair admin angular theme and put it into my application. How do I know what files to import in my page? The component does not exist as a separate page and its really not clear what files it uses.

Comment: You should put code with explanation.

Comment: There is no code! I am trying to pick up a component from a theme... The theme has several js,css, etc files.. I cant upload them here.